# Android Espresso using onData() match on GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-espresso

I have to validate an element with text "congo" in TextViewWithFont

But test case fails when I try

```
    onData(withText("congo"))
            .inAdapterView(withResourceName("gvTiles"))
            .onChildView(allOf(withResourceName("mediaTileLayout"), withChild(withText("congo"))))
            .onChildView(withResourceName("tvMediaName"))
            .check(matches(isEnabled()));
```

and the error it throws is

```
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No data found matching: with text: is "congo" contained values: <[Data: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media@6f801f9 (class: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media) token: 0, Data: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media@7c8e53e (class: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media) token: 1, Data: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media@256af9f (class: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media) token: 2, Data: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media@c6568ec (class: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media) token: 3, Data: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media@fadc4b5 (class: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media) token: 4, Data: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media@7ea174a (class: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media) token: 5, Data: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media@f00a6bb (class: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media) token: 6, Data: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media@5b627d8 (class: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media) token: 7, Data: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media@7c2f731 (class: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media) token: 8, Data: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media@63a5e16 (class: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media) token: 9, Data: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media@a88f397 (class: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media) token: 10, Data: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media@451e984 (class: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media) token: 11, Data: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media@c1ed56d (class: com.thisclicks.adr.db.models.Media) token: 12]>
```

I don't understand why this fails because there is a TextViewWithFont element with "congo" as its text. GridView contains 13 elements and I think the data that are shown in error message are those 13 elements contained in GridView.

Have an idea how to make it work? Thanks!

The ViewHierarchy is like this(summarized)

> +>DecorView{...}
>   |
>   +->ActionBarOverlayLayout{...}
>   |
>   ...
>   |
>   +--------->GridView{id=2131755465, res-name=gvTiles, visibility=VISIBLE ...} ****MATCHES****
>   |
>   +---------->RelativeLayout{id=2131755350, res-name=mediaTileLayout, visibility=VISIBLE ...}
>   |
>   +----------->ImageView{...}
>   |
>   +----------->ImageView{...}
>   |
>   +----------->ImageView{...}
>   |
>   +----------->TextViewWithFont{id=2131755352, res-name=tvMediaName, visibility=VISIBLE, width=78, height=80, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@8ba38a0, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=20.0, y=121.0, text=congo, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
>   |
>   ...
>   |
>   w{id=2131755464, res-name=ivPlus, visibility=VISIBLE, width=37, height=37, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@2be7593, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=130.0, y=0.0}
>   |
>   +---------->RelativeLayout{id=2131755350, res-name=mediaTileLayout, visibility=VISIBLE ...} 
>   |
>   +----------->ImageView{...}
>   |
>   +----------->ImageView{...}
>   |
>   +----------->ImageView{...}
>   |
>   +----------->TextViewWithFont{id=2131755352, res-name=tvMediaName, visibility=VISIBLE, width=147, height=80, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@7350832, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=20.0, y=121.0, text=Copy of time sheet, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
>   |
>   ...

Full ViewHierarchy:

> +>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=768, height=1184, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=1 fl=#1810100 pfl=0x20000 needsMenuKey=2}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
>   |
>   +->ActionBarOverlayLayout{id=16909300, res-name=decor_content_parent, visibility=VISIBLE, width=768, height=1184, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@fc546c, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
>   |
>   +-->FrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=768, height=1040, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$LayoutParams@a7baeca, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=144.0, child-count=1}
>   |
>   +--->DrawerLayout{id=2131755413, res-name=drawer_layout, visibility=VISIBLE, width=768, height=1040, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@7904b58, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
>   |
>   +---->FrameLayout{id=2131755414, res-name=content_frame, visibility=VISIBLE, width=768, height=1040, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams@90ded96, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
>   |
>   +----->LinearLayout{id=2131755415, res-name=fragmentContainer, visibility=VISIBLE, width=768, height=1040, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@a954aed, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
>   |
>   +------>ProgressBar{id=2131755416, res-name=pbLoading, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@eb34d22, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
>   |
>   +------>RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=768, height=1040, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@f54555e, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
>   |
>   +------->RelativeLayout{id=2131755315, res-name=header, visibility=VISIBLE, width=768, height=100, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@af116f8, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=5}
>   |
>   +-------->ImageView{id=2131755317, res-name=ivBack, visibility=VISIBLE, width=80, height=100, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@97687d1, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
>   |
>   +-------->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=124, height=82, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@49caaa4, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=80.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
>   |
>   +--------->RelativeLayout{id=2131755333, res-name=tvPrev, visibility=VISIBLE, width=107, height=33, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@a8cbbc2, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
>   |
>   +---------->TextView{id=2131755334, res-name=tvPrevOriginal, visibility=VISIBLE, width=77, height=27, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@92d3dd3, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=30.0, y=6.0, text=APPLE > , input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
>   |
>   +--------->TextViewWithFont{id=2131755316, res-name=tvHeaderText, visibility=VISIBLE, width=124, height=49, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@54bcd10, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=33.0, text=magma, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
>   |
>   +-------->ImageView{id=2131755426, res-name=linearFragmentContainer_btnPlus, visibility=VISIBLE, width=55, height=55, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@4216009, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=693.0, y=22.0}
>   |
>   +-------->ButtonWithFont{id=2131755427, res-name=linearFragmentContainer_btnRight, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=128, height=60, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@d6ed20e, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=535.0, y=20.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
>   |
>   +-------->ButtonWithFont{id=2131755429, res-name=linearFragmentContainer_btnLeft, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@103e42f, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Clear, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
>   |
>   +------->LinearLayout{id=2131755428, res-name=linearFragmentContainer, visibility=VISIBLE, width=768, height=940, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@54a011a, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=100.0, child-count=2}
>   |
>   +-------->RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=307, height=940, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@6d80741, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
>   |
>   +--------->RelativeLayout{id=2131755315, res-name=header, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@39141c3, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=5}
>   |
>   +---------->ImageView{id=2131755317, res-name=ivBack, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@6b49a40, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
>   |
>   +---------->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@e691a6c, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
>   |
>   +----------->RelativeLayout{id=2131755333, res-name=tvPrev, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@734e4ca, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
>   |
>   +------------>TextView{id=2131755334, res-name=tvPrevOriginal, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@d77263b, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=APPLE > , input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
>   |
>   +----------->ButtonWithFont{id=2131755346, res-name=btnSlideShow, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@6037158, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=SlideShow, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
>   |
>   +----------->TextViewWithFont{id=2131755316, res-name=tvHeaderText, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@e1042b1, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=magma, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
>   |
>   +---------->ImageView{id=2131755318, res-name=ivHeaderPlus, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@7248396, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
>   |
>   +---------->ButtonWithFont{id=2131755319, res-name=btnRight, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@6a7eb17, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
>   |
>   +---------->ButtonWithFont{id=2131755335, res-name=btnLeft, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@9ea4b04, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
>   |
>   +--------->GridView{id=2131755465, res-name=gvTiles, visibility=VISIBLE, width=247, height=880, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@91b96e9, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=30.0, y=30.0, child-count=4} ****MATCHES****
>   |
>   +---------->RelativeLayout{id=2131755350, res-name=mediaTileLayout, visibility=VISIBLE, width=167, height=217, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams@d787d34, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=40.0, y=0.0, child-count=11}
>   |
>   +----------->ImageView{id=2131755340, res-name=ivMediaTileThumbnail, desc=thumbnail, visibility=VISIBLE, width=167, height=217, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@cab575d, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
>   |
>   +----------->ImageView{id=2131755351, res-name=ivGrayTitleBackground, visibility=VISIBLE, width=167, height=105, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@880b8d2, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=112.0}
>   |
>   +----------->ImageView{id=2131755457, res-name=videoPlayButton, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@b8adda3, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
>   |
>   +----------->TextViewWithFont{id=2131755352, res-name=tvMediaName, visibility=VISIBLE, width=78, height=80, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@8ba38a0, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=20.0, y=121.0, text=congo, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
>   |
>   +----------->RelativeLayout{id=2131755341, res-name=ivMediaTileIndicator, visibility=VISIBLE, width=100, height=100, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@a63b0ff, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
>   |
>   +------------>ImageView{id=2131755342, res-name=highlight_indicator, visibility=VISIBLE, width=100, height=100, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@9a3ecc, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
>   |
>   +------------>TextView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=61, height=80, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@e971515, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=NEW, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
>   |
>   +----------->ImageView{id=2131755458, res-name=ivStreaming, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@1fe902a, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
>   |
>   +----------->ImageView{id=2131755459, res-name=ivStreamingOff_bg, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@3cc5e1b, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
>   |
>   +----------->LinearLayout{id=2131755460, res-name=ivStreamingOff, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@ecd84f6, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
>   |
>   +------------>ImageView{id=2131755461, res-name=wifi_off, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@848c0f7, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
>   |
>   +------------>TextView{id=2131755462, res-name=offline_label, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@7cf9b64, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Unavailable offline, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
>   |
>   +----------->ImageView{id=2131755343, res-name=ivDelete, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@815d1cd, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
>   |
>   +----------->ImageView{id=2131755463, res-name=ivMediaTileCorner, visibility=VISIBLE, width=80, height=80, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@8c4fa82, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=87.0, y=0.0}
>   |
>   +----------->ImageView{id=2131755464, res-name=ivPlus, visibility=VISIBLE, width=37, height=37, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@2be7593, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=130.0, y=0.0}

Answer (score 0):

`onData` does not operate on the view hierarchy, but rather matches the data in your adapter. And as the stacktrace suggests that this data is `Media` models.

You will have to write a custom `TypeSafeMatcher` that matches the content of the model, this will help espresso find the position of the View that you are interested in in the adapter. And once the position is found you can use `onChildView()` with normal `ViewMatchers` to validate the actual `ItemView` that is being displayed.